# Debug Spring JSON Serialization

Tags: json, spring, debugging, serialization, jackson

How can I debug in a Spring Boot with Spring Web project how REST endpoint payload data are serialized/deserialized into JSON?

I am unsure which framework for serialization is used (Jackson, Jersey, RestEasy, ...) is used, and if so which instance? I suspect several Jackson instances being active. Any ideas where to hook in for breakpoints or what to enable for debug logging?

Answer (score 2):

`org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter<T>#write` is a method you want to put a breakpoint in in case your application is using Jackson.